# Making dynamic-dropdowns using database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been trying to figure out a way to populate second dropdown from database, based on user's selection in the first dropdown.

So far, [CSS Tricks (Dynamic-Dropdowns)](https://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/) this is the best and most clear answer for my question. Although I am not able to make mine work. (There are 3 examples to populate dropdown, you should check the database one, which is on the bottom of the page.)

I have 2 dropdowns in my settings.php and as tutorial showed I created another php file to print out second dropdown.

This is get-dropdown.php:

```
<script>alert("Here")</script>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$dbConnection = open_connection();

if(isset($_GET['School'])){ $school = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnection, $_GET['School']); }

/* This code will print program options from database.
 *
 * If user's program matches with any of the school from database,
 * mark it as "selected" otherwise, use "Select Your Program" as selected.
 *
 * So, "selected" attribute of user's program will overwrite the "selected"
 * attribute of "Select Your Program".
 * */

$query_programs = "SELECT * FROM PROGRAMS WHERE PROGRAM_SCHOOL='$school' ORDER BY PROGRAM_CODE ASC";
$query_users = "SELECT USER_PROGRAM FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID = $user1_id";

$programs_result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query_programs) or die(mysqli_error($dbConnection));
$users_result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query_users) or die(mysqli_error($dbConnection));

while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users_result)){ $user_program = $data['USER_PROGRAM']; }

foreach($programs_result as $program_result){
    if($user_program == $program_result['PROGRAM_CODE']){
        echo "<option value='$program_result[PROGRAM_CODE]' selected>$program_result[PROGRAM_CODE]</option>";
    }else{
        echo "<option value='$program_result[PROGRAM_CODE]'>$program_result[PROGRAM_CODE]</option>";
    }
}

close_connection($dbConnection);
```

Even the alert on the top doesn't work. I putted there to see if it goes this page. When I selected another option from first dropdown, second dropdown gets empty. Nothing appears inside. Looks like I am making a mistake in settings.php because alert doesn't work on top.

This is some part of my settings.php:

```
<label>
    <span>School:</span>
    <select class="settings-input" name="school" id="school">
        <option value="Select Your School" disabled selected>Select Your School</option>
        <?php
        /* This code will print school options from database.
         *
         * If user's school matches with any of the school from database,
         * mark it as "selected" otherwise, use "Select Your School" as selected.
         *
         * So, "selected" attribute of user's school will overwrite the "selected"
         * attribute of "Select Your School".
         * */

        $query_schools = "SELECT * FROM SCHOOLS ORDER BY SCHOOL_TYPE ASC";
        $query_users = "SELECT USER_SCHOOL FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID = $user1_id";

        $schools_result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query_schools);
        $users_result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query_users);

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users_result)){ $user_school = $data['USER_SCHOOL']; }

        foreach($schools_result as $school_result){
            if($user_school == $school_result['SCHOOL_NAME']){
                echo "<option value='$school_result[SCHOOL_NAME]' selected>$school_result[SCHOOL_NAME]</option>";
            }else{
                echo "<option value='$school_result[SCHOOL_NAME]'>$school_result[SCHOOL_NAME]</option>";
            }
        }
        ?>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
</label>
<label>
    <span>Program:</span>
    <select class="settings-input" name="program" id="program">
        <option value="Select Your Program" disabled selected>Select Your Program</option>
        <script>
            $("#school").change(function(){
                $("#program").load("./lib/get-dropdown.php?school=" + $("#school").val());
            });
        </script>
    </select>
</label>
```

Thank you very much.

**FINALLY FIXED (MY SOLUTION)**
1. I have $dbConnection = open_connection(); to connect database but this function is defined in another file and the necessary information to connect database is stored in another file. So, to my get-dropdown.php I had to require both files. So this is how I fixed the db connection. 
2. Other problem is I pass the school name to get-dropdown.php but the problem is school names contain spaces and this is a problem when you tried to pass in get. So this is what I used to pass get value. I added encodeURIComponent.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#school").change(function(){
            $("#program").load("lib/get-dropdown.php?School=" + encodeURIComponent($("#school").val()));
        });
    });
</script>
```

These were the problems. If you are trying to populate dropdown and no idea about javascript, this is the most easy way. With a little bit jquery, you can achieve it.

Comment: you're mixing a `mysql_` function with `mysqli_`, *why?*

Comment: plus, variables/GET arrays are case-sensitive, another stick in your front (bike) wheel

Comment: I fixed that now. I copied that part from the website and modified it. Didn't realize mysql there. Now it is fixed. But dropdown still doesn't work.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($dbConnection))` to `mysqli_query()` and update your question as to the code you are now using.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I wrote School because it looks much clear for me. Is it bad programming practice?

Comment: `School` and `school` are two different animals altogether ;-) error reporting would have told you that. This whole line is failing you `if(isset($_GET['School'])){ $school = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['School']); }` for 2 reasons.

Comment: I updated the question. Changed the code according to what you have told me. Although Error reporting don't tell me anything.

Comment: `name="school"` + `$_GET['School']` = No love. Surprised that error reporting didn't signal an undefined index School notice.

Comment: I removed that too but that's not the problem. I guess it is about script. I don't know.

Comment: and missing `<form></form>` tags. Sorry to say, but that website contains a lot of bad tutorials which I quickly found out a few years ago. I'm sure you can find something better to work with. Try adding those tags while using/adding the GET method. Leaving out the method defaults to GET though.

Comment: I have from tags. I just copied the necessary part here but thank you Fred I will try to figure out somehow.

Comment: you're welcome. However, if your form's method is POST, would be a reason why it's failing. Since I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, makes it all that much more harder to diagnose.

Comment: If you found the answer, please post it as an answer and accept it, so the question no longer appears as "unanswered"

Comment: @SilverSkin I did. I used to write my answer in question when I found. I've just learned that I can post my answer again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FINALLY FIXED (MY SOLUTION)**
1. I have $dbConnection = open_connection(); to connect database but this function is defined in another file and the necessary information to connect database is stored in another file. So, to my get-dropdown.php I had to require both files. So this is how I fixed the db connection. 
2. Other problem is I pass the school name to get-dropdown.php but the problem is school names contain spaces and this is a problem when you tried to pass in get. So this is what I used to pass get value. I added encodeURIComponent.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#school").change(function(){
            $("#program").load("lib/get-dropdown.php?School=" + encodeURIComponent($("#school").val()));
        });
    });
</script>
```

These were the problems. If you are trying to populate dropdown and no idea about javascript, this is the most easy way. With a little bit jquery, you can achieve it.